# Does a Web Service exist that returns a file from POST string

Tags: javascript, web-services, post, download, gpx

I'm creating a service that produces a driving route from a set of waypoints. Once finished, I need to output a GPX file (basically a XML formatted file with a schema specific to GPS data).

All of my code is in JS, so outputting a file is not straightforward, I know I can write something in PHP, but this complicates things a little for me.

My question is, is there an existing web service where I can simply POST the XML data as a string and it return the file?

Many thanks,

Stu

Comment: Outputting a file how exactly? If it's a service, how would it "output" a file ?

Comment: Give the user an option to save the .gpx file to their local machine for loading into their GPS. The other option I'm considering is to display an iframe with the text to be cut and pasted into a text file and saved, but that's pretty amateur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your string to a blob and then use data URLs to "create" a file and download it:

```js
var data = "<test>test</test>";
var blob = new Blob([data], {type : 'text/xml'});

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'test.xml';
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}));
```

it's a bit hacky but it definitely works.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. Is that cross platform?

Comment: @StuartClarke I managed to get it to work on Chrome and Firefox, unfortunately it seems like Safari don't support the download attribute yet.